# desktopappconverter.exe doesn't support publisher ID on command line?

Tags: desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

Does anyone know why the command line does not allows specifying the publisher's ID, or if there's a workaround?

I'm trying to organize my Desktop Bridge applications to make this easier, but it appears that every time I generate an APPX, I must then go in and manually edit some fields such as the publisher ID. I don't understand why these can't be specified on the `desktopappconverter` command line.

Comment: Which publisher's ID do you mean? Do you mean the Publisher?

Comment: My publisher ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem, and there could be a number of things causing this, most fixed in the most recent versions of Windows 10, the SDKs and Visual Studio. Due to the number of variables possible in different scenarios (packaging dlls versus running over an installer, etc), it's easiest to pinpoint a solution by first updating to the latest of everything and testing across different work stations.

If possible, use the native desktop bridge project within Visual Studio's most recent update,  15.4.4 or higher. It makes the process much simpler.

If that isn't an option for you, #1, make sure that you don't mix publisher name and publisher ID (I made this mistake), and that both attributes conform to the name rules. I noticed DAC is very very picky about punctuation. If need be, update your publisher name at Microsoft to not contain any periods or commas.

If possible, fire up a VM on azure and test running the DAC there on an enterprise version. I have an office of 6 stations and noticed strange bugs and errors here and there on PRO but not as many on the enterprise version.

Let me know if this helps or if I can help further pinpoint the issue